# Check if Screensaver is Active using Mac Bash Script Command

Tags: macos, bash

I've found many useful Bash commands that can execute OS X behaviors from the command line such as:

`screencapture -x -C $FILENAME`

Is there such a command that can check if the screen saver is active?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using this:

```
ps ax|grep [S]creenSaverEngine > /dev/null
if [ "$?" != "0" ] ; then
    # screen saver is not active
else
    # screen saver is active
fi
```

Comment: Love it!  One less need to mess with apple script.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the screensaver in Mac is just an application, so possibly you could check if the process is running...

I think the process is named 'ScreenSaverEngine', but I'm not sure if this is true for the version you have :)

Answer (score 1):

My Mac is at home and I'm not, so I can't test this solution, but how about something like:

```
ps -ef | grep [s]creencapture > nul; echo $?
```

The [] brackets prevent grep from matching this grep command while allowing it to match all other commands containing "screencapture".  (Assuming "screencapture" is the name of the process you're trying to detect.)